# Casting float to int results in incorrect value

Tags: python

The result variable will hold the value 9.0. Why then when I print using "%d" does print return 8?

```
result = (((1.7526 % 0.3048) / 0.3048) * 12)
print(result)        #prints 9.0
print("%f" % result) #prints 9.0
print("%d" % result) #prints 8
```

Answer (score 5):

Floating point arithmetic is inherently imprecise. In Python calculations are typically performed to double precision. Your numbers are not exactly representable to double precision and so are subject to rounding errors. On my machine, `result` is `8.9999999999999929`.

```
>>> result = (((1.7526 % 0.3048) / 0.3048) * 12)
>>> result
8.9999999999999929
>>> print result
9.0
>>> int(result)
8
```

When you print the value it gets rounded to `9.0`, but the actual value stored in `result` in less than `9.0`. So, when you convert `result` to an integer, it is truncated to `8`.

The key issue is that of representability of values. Neither `1.7526` nor `0.3048` are exactly representable in double precision as can easily be seen in the Python interpreter.

```
>>> 1.7526
1.7525999999999999
>>> 0.3048
0.30480000000000002
```

The moral of the story is that you should not expect exact arithmetic when using floating point values. The seminal discussion of this topic is: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` truncates your value which is why you get 8.

Floating point representation in a binary system is an approximation meaning the value that displayed at 9.0 was internally less than 9 and therefore truncated down to 8.

For example all of these yield 3.

```
In [19]: i = 3.1
In [20]: print '%d' %i
3

In [21]: i = 3.4
In [22]: print '%d' %i
3

In [23]: i = 3.7
In [24]: print '%d' %i
3

In [25]: i = 3.9999
In [26]: print '%d' %i
3
```

[This Wikipeadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) article provides some additional background on floating point representation.